# Cannot read existing register value

Tags: windows, cmd, regedit

I found this problem after try to login in game launcher which give me error with reading HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography
After some time and trying solve problem with LAUNCHER i figure out it problem with my system.

When i try read in cmd

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography /v MachineGuid
```

ANY reg value by cmd it give me error about register value doesn't exist.

But if i try read register folders by

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography
```

it read without problem and output folders

Also i checked perms - everyone can read it

UPD: Yeah program and cmd was run from administrate. Also i fixed commands (i type both by mistake)
UPD2: Seems like reading registry values work only with powershell for some reason. By cmd it only read folders of registry but not values

Comment: Also, are you using Run As Administrator?  Just because you use an admin login does not mean that programs run with admin rights.  Unless a manifest asks for rights, an app runs by default with limited rights NOT admin rights

Comment: Yeap i tried run cmd and launcher as Administrator

Comment: I mean. Maybe solve of problem very simple and i m just dumb but i tried almost everything and spend in google to find similar problem at least 2-3 hours.

Comment: Can you post the exact error that your launcher reports? Also, for cmd, it should look like this `reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography" /v MachineGuid`. For Powershell, like this `(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography" -Name MachineGuid).MachineGuid`.

Comment: @FiddlingAway

Error in launcher:
https://i.imgur.com/WpWWnzd.png
Error in cmd with " "
https://i.imgur.com/0r9WoWL.png

Comment: Can you verify that `MachineGuid` exists in the registry? You can do that by opening `regedit.exe`, and navigating to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography`. Also, what happens when you use Powershell, and the command I mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: Yeap it exist i checked it
https://i.imgur.com/EEv0uHJ.png

Comment: With powershell it work and can read value
https://i.imgur.com/wBuoqPp.png

Comment: OK, let's try calling it the way your launcher tries to call it - what happens when you try to run this from cmd? `%windir%\System32\REG.exe QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography /v MachineGuid`

Comment: same error about can't find registry key or folder

Comment: Something is wrong in the setup of your machine, and the launcher is breaking because it can't read the `MachineGuid` - it's most likely programmed to check the `MachineGuid` in one specific way, and the possible failure is not being handled within the launcher. I'm sorry, but I don't have any more suggestions to offer.

Comment: Thank u for your time anyway.
Also i can't read ANY values in register by cmd but folders it read without problem